# gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css color codes ubuntu

Tags: command-line, unity, gtk

for ubuntu 14.04 when editing usr/share/themes/Ambiance/gtk-3.0/gtk-widgets.css  to change colors in some item I would like to know if there is a guide to the corresponding  colors to the numbers in lines such as in `outline-color: alpha (@selected_bg_color, 0.5);`.  Does `0.5` indicate some color, if so where can I find the legend.

Comment: You're better off experimenting by copying the theme over to `~/.themes` with a modified name such as "MyAmbiance". That way, you'll have the original as a back-up and won't need `sudo`.

Comment: I think `alpha` in that context means opacity: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12771102/2072269